# Custom Web Part unsafe control exception

Tags: web-part, safe-controls

I have developed a sln that is composed of 3 different web parts. Everything was working fine, but I renamed the project and assembly at the request of conforming to a naming convention. I deleted the web parts from the wp gallery, retracted the sln and redeployed the newly renamed project. When attempting to preview my web parts in the web parts gallery I receive the error:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SafeControls+UnsafeControlException: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type is not registered as safe.
```

I have checked the web.config to verify that my web parts are under `<SafeControls>` and that the namespace is correct. I've checked each web parts `.spdata` file to check that everything is correct there as well.

Now, I rolled back my sln to the point in time when my project was working (via TFS), deleted the web parts from the gallery, retracted the sln and redeployed once again. I thought reverting back to the working sln would solve my problem, but unfortunately I am met with the `UnSafe` exception again.

Can anyone provide any further thoughts into my situation? I'm running out of places to look. Thanks!

Comment: Are the Version & PublicKeyToken numbers the same between the web.config's safecontrol entry and the assemblies in the GAC?

Comment: @MikeLutge Thanks for the reply. The version & PublicKeyToken between the safecontrol enty and the GAC assembly is the same

Answer (score 0):

You should try delete wsp and install again. We apply this formula and the program was working.

Comment: Retracting and redeploying the .sln = delete wsp and install again.